# Browsers versions without auto-update

Tags: browser, auto-updates

I would like to know which version of the various browsers did **not** update *to the latest version* automatically.

For example, IE8 won't auto-update to IE9 while IE9 auto-updates to IE10.

I think Firefox has this feature from version 4, so the latest non-autoupgrade was 3.6.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Fx3.6 also nagged to be updated. According to  [History of the Opera web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser#Version_10), the "auto update feature" was only introduced in Opera 10 (?!) and I don't think users were auto-updated at version 12.16 (to the all new version 15 - a massive change and huge step backwards).

Comment: What is your idea about that?

Comment: @shgnInc I want to draw up a list of older browsers which may still be around, to test websites' backwards compatibility. I don't want to rely on market share statistics like StatCounter etc.